# Running test on sauce lab non-stop

Tags: automated-tests, saucelabs

Is there a way for me to run a test continuously on sauce lab? (I am trying to run a log in and log out test on our company's website for 24 hours but sauce lab does not have any test schedule system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest configuring your tests to run from a Continuous Integration platform such as Jenkins, Team City etc.  These offer this kind of functionality.  There is a Sauce Labs plugin for Jenkins.
What exactly are you trying to achieve through the test?